# VBA code working in one sheet and returns user-defined type not defined on another

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am working on some code that will save me quite some time.  It is meant to draft up several e-mails to vendors to get a quote on the same item.

Sheet1 I have the vendor data; name, e-mail and something to mark if I want to send that vendor a request or not.  Sheet2 I have the details of the required quote.  The more interesting thing about this is that it will work in one work sheet, that I tested/refined it in, but not its home sheet.  I even tried to copy the information over to a new sheet, and I have the same error; and I don't know why.

```
Public Sub RequestShippingQuote()
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim lCounter As Long
    Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application 'Set Objects
    Dim OutAccount As Outlook.Account
    Set OutAccount = objOutlook.Session.Accounts.Item(4)
    Dim mymsg As String
    For lCounter = 2 To 100
        If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("C" & lCounter).Value) = True Then 'Email if False
        Else
            Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            objMail.To = Sheet1.Range("C" & lCounter).Value 'To
            objMail.Subject = "Quote Request" 'Subject
            mymsg = "Hello," & vbCrLf
            mymsg = mymsg & "Please provide freight quote for the following:" & vbCrLf
            mymsg = mymsg & "Commodity: " & Sheet2.Range("B7").Value & vbCrLf
            mymsg = mymsg & "" & Sheet2.Range("B9").Value & " info is as follows:" & vbCrLf
            mymsg = mymsg & "" & Sheet2.Range("B13").Value & " " & Sheet2.Range("B9").Value & vbCrLf
            mymsg = mymsg & "  " & Sheet2.Range("B18").Value & " W x " & Sheet2.Range("B19").Value & " L x " & Sheet2.Range("B20").Value & " H x " & vbCrLf
            mymsg = mymsg & "  " & Sheet2.Range("B15").Value & " lbs" & vbCrLf
            mymsg = mymsg & "From: " & vbNewLine & Sheet2.Range("B26").Value & vbCrLf
            mymsg = mymsg & "" & Sheet2.Range("B28").Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            mymsg = mymsg & "" & Sheet2.Range("B30").Value & vbCrLf
            mymsg = mymsg & "" & Sheet2.Range("B32").Value & vbCrLf
            mymsg = mymsg & "" & Sheet2.Range("B34").Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            mymsg = mymsg & "Pickup Hours: " & Sheet2.Range("B36").Value & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            mymsg = mymsg & "Notes:" & vbNewLine & Sheet2.Range("B38").Value & vbCrLf
            mymsg = mymsg & "To:" & vbNewLine & Sheet2.Range("B41").Value & vbCrLf
            mymsg = mymsg & "" & Sheet2.Range("B43").Value & vbCrLf
            mymsg = mymsg & "Notes: " & vbNewLine & Sheet2.Range("B53").Value & vbNewLine & Sheet2.Range("B54").Value 'Email Body
            objMail.Body = mymsg

            'objMail.Close (olSave) 'Draft Email
            objMail.Display 'Display Email

            Set objMail = Nothing 'Close the object
    End If
    Next 'May need to be in the if statement, not sure
    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation
End Sub
```

When I try to run this code, I get a "Compile Error: User-Defined type not defined."

I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you had enabled OPTION EXPLICIT your VBA would notify you about your failures to declare variables such as "olMailItem".

When I found this I stopped, other undeclared variables might exist as well.

Comment: I will have to look into this some more.  However, I have olMailItem called in other scripts in exactly the same way and it works as expected.  That also doesn't explain why it worked (but referencing cells that don't have the data I need) in one sheet, but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it worked as intended on one sheet but not any other.

On the one sheet I tested it on I had a library active that was not active on the sheet I was trying to develop this on.  I was unaware each sheet needed the library activated separate from any other, I thought it was a global setting.

The answer, Tools > References > Activate Microsoft Outlook xx.x Object Library

Works as intended now.